# contact form isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, contact-form

I have this website www.nausea.ws and nothing happens when you submit the form, it only deletes the "name field"! I also need the `"your message was sent"` in the same page, below the form to appear! on browser console it says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: subject is not definedcontact_form.js:17 (anonymous function)jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2 v.event.dispatchjquery-1.8.3.min.js:2 o.handle.u
```

Here is the contact_form.js and the contact_form.php:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit-form').click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
            var name  = $('#form_name').val(),
                email  = $('#form_email').val(),
                subject  = $('#form_subject').val(),
                message  = $('#form_message').val(),
                data_html,
                success = $('#success');

            if(name == "")
                $('#form_name').val('Please enter your name.');

            if(subject == "")
                $('#form_subject').val('Please enter your name.');

            if(email == ""){
                $('#form_email').val('Your email is required.');
            }else if(reg.test(email) == false){
                $('#form_email').val('Invalid Email Address.');
            }

            if(message == "")
                $('#form_message').val('Message is required.');

            if(message != "" && name != "" && reg.test(email) != false) {
                data_html = "name=" + name + "&email="+ email + "&message=" + message + "&subject="+ subject;

                //alert(data_html);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'contact_form.php',
                    data: data_html,
                    success: function(msg){

                        if (msg == 'sent'){
                            success.html('<div class="alert alert-success">Message <strong>successfully</strong> sent!</div>')  ;
                            $('#form_name').val('');
                            $('#form_email').val('');
                            $('#form_message').val('');
                        }else{
                            success.html('<div class="alert alert-error">Message <strong>not</strong> sent! Please Try Again!</div>')  ; 
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
            return false;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'contato@nausea.ws';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to gordon@template-help.com');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: You don't need the (function($){... })(jQuery); wrapper, just put the document ready part in the head inside <script> tags.

Comment: @ScottPresnell it might be being used to insulate `$` from other libraries or `noConflict`

Comment: first check you browser console there are errors like `subject` not defined as I can see in my browser console

Comment: it says subject not defined! @singhakash

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: subject is not definedcontact_form.js:17 (anonymous function)jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2 v.event.dispatchjquery-1.8.3.min.js:2 o.handle.u

Comment: The variables after 'var email' are not defined with the var statement.

Comment: do you have an element with `form_subject` as ID ?

Comment: @JCSama yes it's in the html:  <label for="form_subject">Subject</label>
                                <input type="text" name="form_subject" id="form_subject" value="" />

Comment: Could you post your HTML form please !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vyqo59ua/ @JCSama

Comment: waaaaat? lol i dont receive anything! oO

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/vyqo59ua/1/

Comment: @JCSama now i get "Message not sent! Please Try Again!" and in my webmail i receive a blank email! Message from a site visitor
De: para mim - 12/02/2015 21:14 

From: 
E-mail: 
Message:

Comment: You have `if (msg == 'sent'){` so you need to return `sent` as a response to your ajax request when the `$mail_status == true`

Comment: how? i have no clue im so dumb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I drove into your actual sourcecode (the page you are pointing and you have typos
You have this variables

```
  var Nome  = $('#form_name').val(),
                Email  = $('#form_email').val(),
                Assunto  = $('#form_subject').val(),
                Mensagem  = $('#form_message').val(),
                data_html,
                success = $('#success');
```

but you have this code:

```
if(name == "")
            $('#form_name').val('Please enter your name.');

        if(subject == "")
            $('#form_subject').val('Please enter your name.');
```

You should be using `Nome` instead of `name`, `Assunto` instead of `subject` and so on.

Comment: Please, next time grab your actual code and don't point to source page. Read stackoverflow faq.

Comment: ok! i changed it, now it says "message could not be sent, try again" - and in my webmail i received it, but a blank message!!!